# Convert vector type to double type in pyspark

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following spark dataframe:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                  f1|                  f2|
+--------------------+--------------------+
| [380.1792652309408]|[-91793.40296983652]|
|[-18662.02751719936]|[-99674.18149372772]|
|[-736.5125444921572]| [-23736.3626879109]|
|[-143436.24812848...|[-136748.6250801389]|
|[-10325.057466551...|[-108747.85455021...|
|[-9771.868356757912]|[-164454.02688403...|
```

But I want to convert the values in these columns from vector type to double 
output. How can I do so?

Sample output:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                  f1|                  f2|
+--------------------+--------------------+
| 380.1792652309408|-91793.40296983652|
|-18662.02751719936|-99674.18149372772|
|-736.5125444921572| -23736.3626879109|
|-143436.24812848...|-136748.6250801389|
|-10325.057466551...|-108747.85455021...|
|-9771.868356757912|-164454.02688403...|
```

Comment: vector with only 1 value?

Comment: yes the vector has only 1 value

Comment: @thebluephantom What if i have only one column which has vector with 2 values like                                 
|pcaFeatures                              |
+-----------------------------------------+
|[-275435.0611915455,-140539.13293905868] |

Comment: Updated answer, although not really necessary, but it is an improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer. Improvement on the original answer as I did not use Row.

With the enforced down time doing some pyspark and machine learning stuff in the backgroud. Here goes with focus on Vector with cardinality > 1 and same cardinality in all rows as would make sense. And renaming of cols.

You can use this example now:

```
%python
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.sql import Row

source_data = [
    Row(city="AMS", temps=Vectors.dense([-1.0, -2.0, -3.0])),
    Row(city="BRU", temps=Vectors.dense([-7.0, -7.0, -5.0])),
              ]
df = spark.createDataFrame(source_data)

def convertToCols(row):
    return ( tuple(row.temps.toArray().tolist()))

df2 = df.rdd.map(convertToCols).toDF(["C1"]) 
df3 = df2.toDF(*(c.replace('_', 'C') for c in df2.columns)) 
df3.show()
```

returns:

```
+----+----+----+
|  C1|  C2|  C3|
+----+----+----+
|-1.0|-2.0|-3.0|
|-7.0|-7.0|-5.0|
+----+----+----+
```

Important in my example to have used Row as was creating DF in-line.

Comment: the "dummy" column is really very confusing can you please remove it from the dataframe because when i am removing it is giving some error. Please Help i am newbie on spark.

Comment: Updated the answer, a little too quick.